# JSON call in PHP and cURL

Tags: php, json, api, post, curl

I have been trying to call a chinese website API using JSON for over a week now but it is not working.
The URL with the parameters I'm supposed to call is:

```
http://gw.api.jd.com/routerjson?v=2.0&method=jingdong.ware.product.search.list.get&app_key=XXXXXXXX&360buy_param_json={"isLoadAverageScore":"TRUE","isLoadPromotion":"TRUE","sort":"1","page":"1","pageSize":"10","keyword":"裇衫","client":"apple"}&timestamp=2015-05-07 07:28:14&sign=ZZZZZZZZ
```

The following code is not working

```
$data = array("360buy_param_json" => array("isLoadAverageScore" => "TRUE", "isLoadPromotion" => "TRUE", "sort" => "1", "page" => "1", "pageSize" => "10", "keyword" => "'.$this->searchTerm.'", "client" => "apple") );
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://gw.api.jd.com/routerjson?v=2.0&method=jingdong.ware.product.search.list.get&app_key=XXXXXXXX&timestamp='.$TimeInChina.'&sign=ZZZZZZZZZ');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I've also tried several variations, like moving around the 360buy_param_json field but nothing seems to work.

```
$data = array("isLoadAverageScore" => "TRUE", "isLoadPromotion" => "TRUE", "sort" => "1", "page" => "1", "pageSize" => "10", "keyword" => "'.$this->searchTerm.'", "client" => "apple") ;
$data_string = '&360buy_param_json='.json_encode($data).'';
```

Any ideas how to make this puppy work? Thanks
Peace

Comment: Why are you putting the JSON in the post fields when it's supposed to be a URL parameter?

Comment: Because I had no idea what I was doing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is supposed to be in the URL, not the post data. And `360buy_param_json` is the name of the parameter, not part of the JSON object. Since you're putting it into a URL, you also need to use `urlencode` to escape it properly.

```
$data = array("isLoadAverageScore" => "TRUE", "isLoadPromotion" => "TRUE", "sort" => "1", "page" => "1", "pageSize" => "10", "keyword" => "'.$this->searchTerm.'", "client" => "apple");
$data_string = urlencode(json_encode($data));
$ch = curl_init('http://gw.api.jd.com/routerjson?v=2.0&method=jingdong.ware.product.search.list.get&app_key=XXXXXXXX&timestamp='.$TimeInChina.'&sign=ZZZZZZZZZ&360buy_param_json='.data_string);
```